# How to use JavaScript 'Max' validation rule on formatted currency input

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I have an input field for Amount which uses jquery.maskMoney.min.js to format the value as currency, but this seems to be preventing the Max validation rule from working.

I think this is happening because the validator is expecting a numeric value but the mask is prefixing a '$' to the value.

Here is my validation rule:

```
$('#Amount').rules("add", {
    max: function (element) {
        return $('#Total').val();
    },
    messages: {
        max: "Amount exceeds total"
    }
});
```

Is there a way for me to override the actual validation of the amount so I can strip the '$' and validate the numeric value?